Plywood sitting on top of collar ties in garage
I purchased a home and in the garage there is plywood that is resting on top of the collar ties (at least I think they're collar ties). The plywood isn't fastened to the collar ties, it's just resting up there. Is it ok to remove these pieces of plywood? Want to build a garage golf simulator and remove the plywood and put netting up instead.



Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works. The comments above are not answers.

Rafter ties, technically. Collar ties would be higher up the truss.
Someone apparently made some storage up there. The plywood is not structural.
